# How to display a product's multiple price with a better UX?

Tags: ipad, pricing

We are re-designing a menu. In this menu, an item can have multiple prices.

[image]

If there are more than 3 price options, it can be slide to the left or right. But sometimes the user cannot understand if there are more prices.

If we display the list line by line, the right of the price list will be empty.

So what should I do?

Comment: Is this on a desktop, tablet or mobile? Will give people the idea of space to work with.

Comment: It is a tablet. I uploaded an image but there is an error.

Answer (score 1):

**Consider using a 'From' price, and providing a way of viewing all pricing options**

A user interested in a Cobb Salad could click to see all prices, and add their choice directly from a modal overlay.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1k7He.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I cannot see your mockup, also the image that I uploaded is not being displayed. There is a problem with imgur I guess.

Comment: I think the problem might be in your end. I can see both the image you uploaded and my mockup.

Comment: I could see it via VPN, interesting. Thank you for the mockup, looks great. Problem is, our clients want to show it in one place. Actually we have a lot of space in the detail page, because there is only 1 Item.